# PHP Sum column values if multiple keys are the same MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table which results are fetched from mysql query. These values are for example only.

```
Item | Location |  CheckIn   |  Checkout  | Quantity

  A  |   abc    | 10/10/2015 |            |    20
  A  |   abc    |            | 11/10/2015 |    10
  B  |   def    | 11/10/2015 |            |    25
  A  |   abc    | 12/10/2015 |            |    5
  B  |   def    |            | 13/10/2015 |    10
  B  |   def    | 14/10/2015 |            |    3
  A  |   ghi    | 14/10/2015 |            |    30
```

I want to total up the quantity based on same item and location, and with condition. For example, if item check in, quantity of the item is added up into the location. If item check out, quantity of the item is subtracted from total current quantity of item at specific location.

I have second table which will display each item at specific location with total quantity of the item at that location. What I have so far is something like this:

```
Item | Location | Total Quantity

  A  |   abc    |  20
  A  |   abc    |  10
  B  |   def    |  35
  A  |   abc    |  40
  B  |   def    |  30
  B  |   def    |  33
  A  |   ghi    |  63
```

The expected result should be like this:

```
Item | Location | Total Quantity

  A  |   abc    |  15
  B  |   def    |  18
  A  |   ghi    |  30
```

The code I did so far for second table:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM itemloc INNER JOIN tblitem ON itemloc.itemId=tblitem.itemId INNER JOIN tblloc ON itemloc.locId=tblloc.locId");
$loc = array();
$total = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$checkout = $row['itemLocCheckOut'];
if($loc[$row['locId']] = $row['itemId']){
    if(is_null($checkout)){
        $qty = +$row['itemLocQty'];
        }
    else{
        $qty = -$row['itemLocQty'];
        }
$total+=$qty;
$name = $row['itemNm'];
$locnm = $row['locNm'];
}
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $locnm;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make an array with first index item string and the second the Location.
For each row read, I would do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $item = $row['item'];
    $location = $row['location'];
    if(!isset($result[$item][$location]))
        $result[$item][$location] = 0;
    if(is_null($row['itemLocCheckOut']))
        $result[$item][$location] += $row['quantity'];
    else
        $result[$item][$location] -= $row['quantity'];
}
```

At the end, pass with 2 foreach on the table:

```
foreach($result as $k1 => $v1)
    foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2)
         echo "Item $k1 location $k2 has $v2 quantity"
```

Comment: Hi I've tried your code but error occurs because I need to echo the result within a table. I'm getting a warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Can you try doing a var_dump($result). It should help out on the error.

Comment: I'm getting another error Warning:Cannot use a scalar value as an array at $result[$item][$location]+=$row['itemLocQty'];

Comment: i got the error fixed by declaring new array which is $loc=array(); and replace $result[$item][$location] with $loc[$item][$location]. However the total quantity is not correct. It fetches last amount of quantity from the first table. For example, based on the example I give up there, item A at location abc has quantity of 5

Comment: Please check if you used += and -= in the if_null condition.

Comment: Yes. I did use the += and -= but the calculation still did'nt work..thanks for your help btw :) if u have any other suggestion..do drop your comment here :)

Comment: I tested localy with this code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ef725a889ebb2990b80a2fed6d38d2f1559179d

Comment: Problem solved!! The calculation works fine after I rearrange the { } for if else ...Thank you so much!!